# Relationship between Big O vs little o

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

I'm having trouble with some statements using the Big $O$ and little $o$ notations.

> Let $f(x)=O(x^2), g(x)=O(x^3)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$. Which of the following statements are true:
>
> 1. $f(x)=o(x)$ for $x\rightarrow 0$
> 2. $f(x)=o(x^2)$ for $x\rightarrow 0$
> 3. $f(x)g(x)=O(x^5)$ for $x\rightarrow 0$
> 4. $f(x)+g(x)=O(x^3)$ for $x\rightarrow 0$

By the sum and product properties of the Big O, I know that the third and the fourth statements are correct but  I'm having trouble with the first two. By my understanding $O(h(x)) $ loosely states that  "grows no faster than $h(x)$" and $o(h(x))$ loosely states that "grows much slower than $h(x)$". But so far when I attempt to look at it formally it doesn't make much sense

1. Formally $f(x)=o(x)$ for $x\rightarrow0$ when for all  $c>0$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ around $0$ such that $\forall x\in U$, $|f(x)| \leq c|x|$. Since $f(x)=O(x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow0$ then there exists $k>0$ such that $\forall x\in U$ so  $ |f(x)| \leq k|x^2|$ holds true. Since $|x^2|\leq |x|$ holds true when $x\in (-1,1)$ then for sufficiently large $c$: $|f(x)|\leq k|x^2| \leq c|x|$ holds true in $U$.
2. Since $f(x)=O(x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow0$ then there exists $k>0$ such that $\forall x\in U$ so  $ |f(x)| \leq k|x^2|$ holds true. We can choose sufficiently large $c$ so that the relations $|f(x)| \leq k|x^2| \leq c|x^2|$

I'd appreciate the help if someone could tell me where I'm goung wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to be careful with the limit. Here, you are considering $x \to 0$. Hence the Landau notation actually measures *decay* and not *growth*. In particular, you should think about 4. again.

Now to your question. I think it is easiest to use the limsup definition of $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{o}$. So $f \in \mathcal{o}(h)$ if and only if $\limsup\limits_{x \to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\right| = 0$ and $f \in \mathcal{O}(h)$ if and only if $\limsup\limits_{x \to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\right| < \infty$. From this it is immediately obvious why 2. cannot be true in general. For 1. we get
$$\limsup\limits_{x \to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| = \limsup\limits_{x \to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^2}x\right| \leq \limsup\limits_{x \to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right| \limsup\limits_{x \to 0} \left|x\right| = 0.$$